# How to cast a object as TRttiType

Tags: delphi, casting, rtti

I'm working with an ORM (Aurelius), and need to cast a object as TRttiType.

The TRttiType was obtained from TRtticontext.FindType.

```
ISptModel = interface(IInterface)
  ['{688431B1-2895-4FE2-AD18-8A7892289956}']
end;

TCidade = class(TInterfacedObject, ISptModel)
end;
```

```
var
  FObjectInstance: ISptModel;

LType := LContext.FindType('Spt.Cidade.Model.TCidade');

Manager.SaveOrUpdate(LType(FObjectInstance)); // I need something like this, but doesnt work
Manager.SaveOrUpdate(TCidade(FObjectInstance)); // This works
```

It has to be cast as TCidade so Aurelius can persist the object correctly.

Comment: You can't use RTTI for casting. The type being casted to must be known at compile time

Comment: Is there any other way to do it?

Comment: This won't work. When you call FindType you are getting the class type. This isn't your instance of the class. Depending on the version of Delphi that you have, you could cast your interface as a TObject (not ideal) or add a method to get the object to ISptModel. That method would just return self.

Comment: Am I correct your using Aurelius from TMS Software? Maybe then you can mention it as reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use `LType` like you want to.

You probably just need to cast the interface as a `TObject` like so:

```
Manager.SaveOrUpdate(FObjectInstance as TObject);
```

Comment: @r-hoek I can not cast as TObject, it has to be cast as TCidade so Aurelius can persist the object correctly.

Comment: I’m not familiar with the way Aurelius works. But when it uses Rtti itself, casting to TObject would allow that framework to save the object anyway as internally it will see the actual class type of the object. Have you tried it?

Comment: @FlávioOliveiraESantos You are wrong, Aurelius takes a TObject in SaveOrUpdate, The actual type of the variable that you are passing in isn't important, the object knows what type it is.

Comment: @R.Hoek Your comment is correct. Aurelius takes an object.

Comment: You two are correct, cast as TObject works! I made a mistake.